# JMeter test simultaneous users with sequential requests

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, simultaneous

I have a problem. I would like to do sequential http request with JMeter but with simultaneous users.

Example : I've got 100 users and at the same time they try to do :

```
Login
Do stuff 1
Do stuff 2
Logout
```

In this order.

In my results I don't want to have

User 1 do :

```
login 
stuff 1
stuff 2
logout
```

after that the

```
user 2 login
stuff 1 
stuff 2
logout
```

I would like to have at the same time User 1 and 2 try to login after that they do their stuff and logout.

So, in my results I can have this example :

```
Login user 1 
Login user 2 
Stuff 1 user 1 
Stuff 2 user 1 
Stuff 1 user 2 
Stuff 2 user 2 
Logout user 2 
Logout user 1
```

Thanks,

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer), I believe it is exactly what you need.

Comment: I think what he is asking is possible with default behavior. If he needs to run requests synchronously then use sync timer but if he needs it for multiple requests, then performance wise it will be quite big impact and such use case doesn't make sense.